# White page when changing route in Angular 5 + ElectronJS

Tags: angular, electron, angular-routing

I'm having a problem with my Angular5 + ElectronJS app. When I run the app in the browser, everything works fine, but with ElectronJS, every time I click an item in the navbar, that should change the route of the app, electron just goes into a blank page, displaying absolutely nothing in the console either.

From what I've read, this is a problem with how Angular's router works. Things I have tried (unsuccesfully):

- Change my `<base href=>` in index.html from `'/'`, to `''` and `./`.
- Change `imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)]` to `imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { useHash: true })]` in app-routing.ts.
- Using different `href` in my hyperlinks, like: `<a href='palas'>`, `<a href='#/palas'>`, `<a href='#!/palas'>`
- Combinations of pretty much everything listed before.

Here's my pretty basic and standard app-routing.module.ts:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { HomeComponent } from './home/home.component';
import { ShovelComponent } from './shovel/shovel.component';
import { TruckComponent } from './truck/truck.component';
import { ShovelsComponent } from './shovels/shovels.component';
import { TrucksComponent } from './trucks/trucks.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: HomeComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'palas',
    component: ShovelsComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'camiones',
    component: TrucksComponent
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { useHash: true })],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

For now, I only found 1 thing that kind of worked, but not really. In my hyperlinks, if I do `<a routerLink="/palas">` it will take me succesfully to that route, and will load the component. This is not working for me, because i have some services, that need to start at the same time as the component is loaded, and right now they are starting with the app, and are already running when the other components are loaded.

Comment: I spent the last 2 weeks converting our Angular 5 app into an Electron app and had a hard time solving routing issues, but I figured them all out. If you give me like 2 hours from this post, I would be more than glad to help you out via chat.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Didn't see your comment on time, but in the end, i ended up coding a work-around in order to be able to use `routerLink` instead of `href` in my hyperlinks. It may still be useful if you could try to explain how to deal with routing when converting Angular 5 apps into Electron, because my app is still in development, and I may need to add a lot more routing in the future.

Comment: Oh if you are clicking an anchor and just going to another route, then yes, routerLink is the way to go. If you want to open a route into a new BrowserWindow, then that is another can of worms.

Comment: Maximiliano Andres Friedl Schw Can you please share how did you fix it? I am stuck at the same problem ... ended up using *ngIf to switch between components ... because this inconsistency drove me mad. It even brakes the build --watch for me, once it goes blank page, recompiling doesn't affect the hosted app on Electron...

Comment: Posted an answer with what I ended up doing.

Answer (score 2):

In case someone else has the same problem, I ended up keeping the routing as is. That would be:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    redirectTo: 'palas',
    pathMatch: 'full'
  },
  {
    path: 'palas',
    component: ShovelsComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'camiones',
    component: TrucksComponent
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

And for my hyperlinks, I used `routerLink="{path}"` instead of `href="{path}"`

```
<a routerLink="/" routerLinkActive="active"> Home </a>
<a routerLink="/palas" routerLinkActive="active"> Palas </a>
<a routerLink="/camiones" routerLinkActive="active"> Camiones </a>
```

As for the `index.html`, I used `<base href="./">`

With this, I'm able to navigate through my different routes inside of the ElectronJS app and inside a web browser.

As for my problem with the service not reloading, I ended up coding a work-around to re-start everything the service does in a public function, and I call it from the constructor of the component that is loading.

Comment: Interesting ... I have the exact same setup and I am still occasionally getting white pages when navigating... I had been using the routerLink to begin with

Comment: Wow, I'm not sure how you can fix it then. You said "occasionally", have you tried to consistently be able to replicate the white page? If you can, this could point to the root of the problem.

Comment: I figured out what's causing the issues .. basically I have configured an npm command that first fires up electron and then builds the hosted app. If am doing it in this order and using routing, it hosts the prebuild app, but once the app is build again and needs to be re-hosted i get a blank page... hence I was getting the feeling it was happening at random. Running commands in reverse goes ok, but what annoys me is this issue renders "build --watch" useless ...